# Using iMacros for Firefox to run an external exe?

Tags: firefox, imacros

I want to run an iMacros .js script from the free Firefox version to open an executable file (via the command line).

I want to put this script on a loop, so this has to be done repeatedly.

I have looked online and it looks like the free version does not allow this directly. I am looking for a workaround. Perhaps using a bat file and a scheduler? I am not sure about it.

It looks like it should be simple enough. Is there anyone out there who has done something like this before?

Hamza

Comment: It's possible of course. But such solution is not out there to be found. I myself am readyto work on it for a good fee. $$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in firefox with this .js command:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\app.exe");
file.launch();
```

You can also launch any app or file of your choice by this.